# PHP: Can using strlen/mb_strlen incorrectly ever result in security issues?

Tags: php, string

I use UTF-8 across all my websites and so when I count string lengths I use [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). It occurred to me though someone could easily create a page in another encoding like iso-8859-1 and submit it to my script that is expecting it in UTF-8.

Are there any scenarios where this could cause serious (i.e. security) issues with a website? I'm guessing the worst that can happen is you get some characters that won't display correctly but thought I'd check if anything more sinister can happen.

Comment: No expert, but I think that's the only thing yeah. Edit: Assuming you sanitize user input if you're using it in databases etc.

Comment: You're describing CSRF https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: You'll have to escape any malicious code right before outputting it. Like `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($var), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @kernal What could be malicious though? Surely, the worst that can happen is you can an unknown character. That's pretty much what I want confirming. If you can do anything malicious can you please provide an example?

Comment: Not expert too, but the only problem that can occurs is bad conversion and there's no convertion to "Ã\0", "Ã<", "Ã>", "Ã'" or 'Ã"'. The only occurence of bad conversion that can be interpreted in your HTML sources is "Ã&" but this have no effect for CSRF (or XSS) attacks, only display issues